# A *lot* of base system devices missing drivers, along with a few others

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

A few months back, my Windows files got corrupted, and I had to wipe my `C:` drive (all of my data besides my OS is on another drive) and re-download Windows. However, since re-downloading it I've had issues, namely with sound and with my USB ports; they only work for certain devices.

I have a feeling it's due to missing drivers, and upon checking my Device Manager, I found this:

[image: screenshot]

(the "Base System Device" list goes a bit higher, but I figured the bottom is more important. All of this is listed under "other devices" in device manager.

I have searched and found other questions pertaining to this, but all others seemed to have only a couple of these, and I am unsure of what could cause there to be so many on my system. My computer is a custom build, GPU: Nvidia GTX 970, CPU: i7-5930K, running Windows 7.

**Edit 1**: Certain things work when plugged in. My usb mouse and keyboard both work from any of my usb ports. However, most things do not work. My printer is not even recognized as a device, and neither is my phone. (the phone does charge, though)

Comment: Have you tried getting the latest version of your motherboard drivers? I've seen this happen when they're missing or incorrect. That would also explain your sound issue, assuming you're using onboard sound.

Comment: @udjamaflip You are exactly right. I had grabbed some of the drivers, but not the chipset, as TomEus said below. Thanks for getting me started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your "chipset" drivers are not installed. To fix that

1. Find your motherboard manufacturer - probably best during the boot, or even better by opening the case and finding the manuf/model
2. Go to the manuf website and look for the chipset driver it is #5 from the top [Intel board drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/50347/Intel-Desktop-Board-D848PMB)
3. After installing and reboot you should only see specific USB peripherals missing - for example you may need to re-install the printer driver

Comment: Chipset worked perfectly, now i'm just grabbing USB drivers. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I updated the drivers through the official website, but nothing helped.

I decided to try updating the drivers using the **IObit Driver Booster** application.
After the update, everything worked.